# Which ocr to use for recognising different fonts of text?(BLACKADDER ITC etc)

Tags: text, ocr

i want to use ocr(optical character recogniser) on BLACKADDER ITC font. I
was searchin a lot for such ocr Which works
on different fonts. Can Anyone Pls help me?
(I've searched So many ocr's like SimpleOcr Which works Good on text of standard fonts like times new Roman.)

Comment: Using OCR on handwritten text or "distressed" style fonts is an iffy proposition at best. Programs such as Tesseract OCR could be trained to recognize new fonts but I suspect that the swashes in the Blackadder font would make that very unreliable. Just out of curiosity, what is the source document type you are tying to scan? If you have something like a PDF file it may be possible to extract the text content from the document (rendered in the Blackadder font) rather than attempting to OCR it.

Answer (score 0):

With Tesseract http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

you can use some training tools to increase your detection ratio.

To do that, you have to create a "training image" like in this thread :

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

It is hard to have a correct result, but you can try for your sample as if your font looks complicate to be learned correctly.

Hope it will help you !